# How to use chaining in c++ for collision without creating the code for hash table?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

I am new to hashmaps and I wanted to know if I can use unordered_map for cases with collision.

or should I start learning java? because it has the hash table, which makes everything easy for programming for tree.

Comment: `unordered_map` is a hash table implementation that handles collisions internally using the *separate chaining* approach - though it's not generally obvious or interesting to the code using the `unordered_map` whether there was a collision or not.  C++ also provides other types of hash tables: `unordered_set` (which uses a hash table to store keys, but there are no associated values), and `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap` - which allows duplicate keys.  There are also lots of 3rd party hash table implementations you can download if you have specialised needs.

Comment: yeah ...I had researched it and found the same. so thanks a lot! Using c++ is not bad as people make it look like after all, I guess.

Comment: it tends to be people who aren't good programmers who struggle with it, then they blame the language....

Comment: you are right. Java is verbose, c++ is complicated, python is garbage ...they really have good word choices ;)